# TextView with custom color attribute not renders in Layout preview

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

`TextView` with custom color attribute not renders in Layout preview.

I have defined attributes `attr.xml` inside values folder.

```
<attr name="secondary_text_color" format="color"/>
```

And override this color in `style` xml for dark and light themes.

Inside `TextView`:

```
android:textColor="?attr/secondary_text_color"
```

Layout preview show error, however the app work as expected.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at android.widget.TextView.updateTextColors(TextView.java:5773)
> at android.widget.TextView.setHintTextColor(TextView.java:5047)
> at android.widget.TextView.applyTextAppearance(TextView.java:4053)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1604)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:968)
> at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:964)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor273.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:776)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:129)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
> at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:308)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
> at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change the default theme to desired them, in this case light or dark theme, in layout preview control panel.
[image]

Or, set app theme to your desired default theme in manifest `application` tag:

`android:theme="@style/MyTheme"`